# What's the best GPS servers to use in positioning

Tags: java, gps

I'm building a GPS Java application used in positioning and tracking services and it designed as like the following figure:

[image: application demonstration]

The point here is that i want to know the best server i can use in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build your own cellphone app and use your server or hack Nasa servers :)
At cellphone, when app started and user agree to use GPS and send it to yourapp.yourserver.com than it will be available at your server, where is the employee.  Now the boss can use his browser and check what data is stored at server side.

Otherwise:
1 GPS coordinates are transmitted from satellites. Hack and catch who's phone asked and where is now. good luck with that... 
2 GSM ( not GPS ) method: each sim card has an ID. Hach the network operator server and ask where is it that SIM card. Good luck with that too.

I would suggest the first solution, but technically are others too, at least teoretically.